# how to receive data with out binding the socket in winsock

Tags: c++

I have an application which sends data to my 'localhost'/'127.0.0.1' or any ip to particular port '5000'. this port is already been occupied. if i want to see which data is been sent at '5000' port.

for this i wrote an client application as follows:

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

```
cout<<"\n Hi "<<endl;

WSAData wsd;

if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsd)!=0)
{
    cout<<"\n WSA Failed : "<<endl;
    return 0;
}

SOCKET sock;

int bytesRecv;

char recvBuf[1024]="Hello";

sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

if(sock==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout<<"\n Socket Creation Failed"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

SOCKADDR_IN client;

int clientAddrSize=sizeof(client);

client.sin_family=AF_INET;
client.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
client.sin_port=htons(5000);


if(connect(sock,(SOCKADDR *)&client,sizeof(client))==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout<<"\n Connection Failed "<<endl;
    wprintf(L"Connection Failed %d",WSAGetLastError());

}
else
{
    cout<<"\n Connection Established "<<endl;
}



    while(sock!=SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        //memset(recvBuf,'\0',1024);

    bytesRecv=recvfrom(sock,recvBuf,50,0,(SOCKADDR *)&client,&clientAddrSize);




    if (bytesRecv == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    {
    wprintf(L"sendto failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
    //while(1);
    }
    puts(recvBuf);




    cout<<"\n "<<bytesRecv<<endl;


    cout<<"\n Sent Buffer : "<<recvBuf<<endl;

    while(1);

}

    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

}

it is working fine till 'bytesRecv=recvfrom(sock,recvBuf,50,0,(SOCKADDR *)&client,&clientAddrSize);'. it is neither throwing any WSAGetLastError or giving number of bytes received. What could be the possible reasons. how to make this program working and get to see the data transmitted to my localhost at 5000 port.

how can make my client program to receive the data at same location as my server is sending the data at that location.

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic mis-understanding of sockets. If the port is already occupied, you CAN'T receive data on it with your program. That doesn't make any sense, and would be a massive security problem if you could do it.

If you want to see the data that's going to another program, you'll need a network sniffer like Wireshark.

Comment: How Wireshark will be getting that data and showing us. I want to acess that data and use that data for some other application